# How to prevent air conditioner pipe from molding?

Tags: cleaning, house-cleaning

My bedroom has a split-type air conditioner. Between conditioner and compressor there is a pipe for refrigerant. Moisture condenses on the pipe for a long time, and it has thick mold. I plan to clean it. After clean, how do I prevent it from having mold again? Thank you!

Comment: There is a specific product for this, and it's not really worth trying to lifehack a substitute. What countries call it varies, but most hardware stores should understand a request for "pipe insulation". It looks like a pipe itself, with a split in one or two places depending on how flexible it is. The single split version that comes with built in self adhesive tape [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LoVS6.jpg) will be what you want. The [rigid version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRV83.jpg) that self closes is a pig to get around sharp bends so only choose it if your pipe is a straight run

Comment: Pipe insulation comes in varying inner and outer diameters; measure your pipe and choose one with an inner diameter a bit larger than the pipe. To prevent condensation that encourages mold to grow, an interior surface needs to be at least 12 Celsius so if even after adding the insulation the surface is colder than this it could experience condensation, and more insulation (a thicker insulation or another layer, this time with an inner diameter that matches the outer diameter of the first insulation layer) will be needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious way would the to thermally insulate the pipe. In this way, the warm air in the room does not come in contact with the cold pipe.

I do not know if you could / should do this by yourself, for safety reasons. Please contact a specialized air-conditioning service for advice.

If the unit is still under guarantee, call the service to fix it for you for free.

Besides the problem with the mod, there is also an efficiency problem - ultimately, a money problem, your money lost in inefficient cooling.